# Do invisible UIButtons affect rendering performance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have UITableViewCells that I've drawn everything I could into the contentview for performance, but I have buttons that I still need to interact with.

I've drawn the image for the buttons into the contentview and just put some invisible uibuttons on top of them.  Does it still hit performance even if you can't see the buttons themselves? I could test it myself, but this seems like a handy question to have on SO.

Comment: I dare say there is no one answer to this. Over all versions of iOS (plus future ones!) and all versions of hardware. I imagine that if Apple figure out that something does not need to be rendered that the process is faster!

Comment: Opacity, dotted lines, and pattern images are what put the most stress on the renderer.  If your button has an alpha of 0, it may well not be rendered, but if you set it to 0.1, then the rendering engine has to blend it with the background views and layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this in the Simulator by selecting Debug - Color Blended Layers. The darker the colour, the greater the impact on drawing performance.

Comment: So I used your strategy to test invisible buttons I've added to a complex UITableViewCell that I've done all the drawing myself.  The buttons did NOT affect performance, even with selectors attached to them.  Still getting 60 FPS.